# Difference Between React Context API and Apollo Cache Memory

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client, react-context

I am really confused about React Context API and Apollo Cache. Do I need to use both of them in my project?

Comment: apollo is mainly for graphql fetched data, it can be used for global app state ... react context can be used for many different things when deeply nested components need to communicate: app state, theme handling, i18n etc.